# parallel rendering of multiple QGraphicsView

Tags: multithreading, qt, parallel-processing, qthread, qgraphicsview

I have a QMainWindow with multiple QGraphicsView.

Each instance of QGraphicsView does an independent work and there is no shared data among them.

Since in sequential rendering mode, it takes too much of time I want to render each QGraphicsView in seperated thread in order to improve the performance of my application but Qt does not seem to support it.

Is there any possible solution to overcome this problem?

Thank you for your time and consideration

Comment: Without seeing any code I'm guessing but in general, no, the rendering can't be spread across multiple threads.  You need to establish exactly where the performance bottleneck is in your code before you can fix it.

Comment: The bottleneck of my app is within the paint() function. As I have multiple paint function (multiple graphicsView) my app is going to be so slow

Answer (score 0):

Paint to independent pixmaps in separated threads and than paint those pixmaps in your QGraphicsViews in the main thread.